# filtering objects in django with special rules

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can you do a filter and do something like this in django

model.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id , thing != 0)

I mean i wnat do something that it get only objects that their thing in not 0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclude() method will do the job.

```
 model.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id).exclude(thing = 0)
```